# SELECT from a table when in transaction

Tags: c#, sql-server, transactions

I am trying to update a table in SQL Server in a transaction, and separately while the transaction is still open, `SELECT` from that same table. When I try to `SELECT` from the table while the transaction is still active, SQL Server just keeps spinning and doesn't return any results.

I am using `SqlConnection` in C#. I call `SqlConnection.BeginTransaction()`, execute some statements and then commit the transaction.

The statements I am executing look something like this:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE [Table]
INSERT INTO [Table] ...
INSERT INTO [Table] ...
...
```

I still would like to be able to `SELECT` from `[Table]` while those statements are executing in the transaction, as there can be many that will potentially take several minutes to complete.

I've tried using `WITH(NOLOCK)` in my `SELECT` statement but that didn't seem to make any difference.

```
SELECT * FROM [Table] WITH(NOLOCK)
```

This query does work as soon as the transaction is committed. Is it possible to `SELECT` from that table while there is still an open transaction? I essentially want to `SELECT` anything from that table in the state it was in before the transaction started.

Comment: `TRUNCATE TABLE` takes a [schema lock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/truncate-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) for the transaction which I think will prevent any other sessions accessing the table. Try removing that to see if thats the issue.

Comment: Thank you, worked like a charm. Just replaced `TRUNCATE TABLE` with `DELETE FROM` and now it works.

Comment: Do you really want to read the dirty (uncommited) data?  If not use SNAPSHOT or READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT and get non-blocking but consistent reads.

Comment: To further David's point, it is rare someone should ever use `WITH (NOLOCK)`. That hint increases your risk of data issues. Setting the proper isolation levels, such as what David suggested above, is the proper way to allow reading from a table without being blocked from simultaneous writes to that same table.

Comment: Just to follow up on this, my solution to use `DELETE FROM` instead of `TRUNCATE TABLE` will cause a loss in performance especially for large tables. Is there any alternative?